# Nightwatch/selenium - Error: Unable to access jarfile

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, selenium-server

I'm trying to run some functional tests but i got this error.

```
Starting selenium server... There was an error while starting the Selenium server:

Error: Unable to access jarfile 
./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/3.0.1-server.jar
```

This's my configuration in my nightwatch.json file

```
"selenium": {
"start_process": true,
"start_session" : true,
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"port": 4444,
"log_path": "./test/e2e/",
"server_path": "./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/selenium-server/3.0.1-server.jar",
"cli_args" : {
  "webdriver.chrome.driver" : "./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/chromedriver/2.27-x64-chromedriver"
 }
}
```

Comment: Try running night watch with the --verbose flag set. That should get you more information about the error.

Answer (score -1):

Check your server_path. Is the file in that location or in some other? Is that the actual Selenium jar & version? Adjust as necessary.

Comment: The path it's ok, but the version it's not the latest.

Comment: Checking the path is a Troubleshooting step. It happens to be the first one, just because it didn't solve your problem, doesn't mean is should get a downvote.

Comment: Ok, have you tried  running with the  --verbose flag?